# Laravel - First segment to be optional

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm fairly new to Laravel and I want my website to be multilingual. And I store the chosen language `slug` in `Session`. But how can I make my urls display which language was chosen:

```
Route::get('/{lang?}/signup', array(
    'as' => 'signup',
    'uses' => 'UsersController@getSignup'
));
```

http://example.com/en/signup - if I get the first segment with URL::segment(1) and pass it to the `Session` everything is OK. With the `Route` I posted above I get **4oh4** if I open the second link.

So basically I can't think of a way that will make both http://example.com/en/signup and http://example.com/singup to work.

The first link should change the user language and the second should use the value stored in `Session` to fetch the results for this language.

**Edit:**

I'm trying to make something like a CMS, where I have set some keys in a table in the database - `languages`:

`id` - (int) AI, `name` - (varchar) - Language's name, `prefix` - (varchar) - Language's prefix

And another table that stores the `translations` of certain parts in the website:
`id` - (int) AI, `key` (eg. signup_form_name), `value` (eg. My sign up form)

And I have this function in my `helpers.php`:

```
function _t($key, $language = NULL)
{
    if(is_null($language))
        $language = Session::get('currLang');
    $string = DB::table('translations')
        ->where('key', $key)
        ->pluck('value');
    return (!is_null($string)) ? $string : $key;
}
```

Comment: I don't think having two URLs pointing to the same content is a good thing (`/en/singup` and `/singup`). I would redirect to the stored language in `Session`. And make the first segment to always have the lang code. You could compare the first segment to an array containing the list of all the lang codes you are expecting.

Comment: @azeós, thanks for your response. I've update my question with detailed information. I'm not using `Locale` in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

How could it differentiate

```
en
```

from

```
signup
```

?

Those are just two strings. The only way could be to hit

```
http://example.com//signup
```

Instead of

```
http://example.com/signup
```

Because this way you are explicitly telling Laravel that you are not passing the first route parameter. But that will not work, because Laravel will not understand it too, there's an issue about this in Github.

So this is one of your options:

```
Route::get('/signup/{lang?}' ...);
```

So you can hit it as

```
http://example.com/signup
```

or

```
http://example.com/signup/en
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/{lang?}/signup', array(
    'as' => 'signup',
    'uses' => 'UsersController@getSignup'
))->where('lang', '(en|br)');
```

The key problem here is that you need to hard code the langs into your controller, but it should work...